# Unable to apply lowercase_normalizer setting in elasticsearch using rest client

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to apply lowercase normalizer while creating a new index through elasticsearch rest client using the below code.

```
CreateIndexRequest indexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(index);
//normalizer settings
String settings = "{\"settings\":{\"analysis\":{\"normalizer\":{\"my_normalizer\":{\"type\":\"custom\",\"filter\":[\"lowercase\",\"asciifolding\"]}}}}}";
indexRequest.settings(settings, XContentType.JSON);
indexRequest.mapping(source, XContentType.JSON);
CreateIndexResponse indexResponse = client.indices().create(indexRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

But i keep getting the below error from elasticsearch.

```
    Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/knowledgebase?master_timeout=30s&timeout=30s], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.normalizer.my_normalizer.filter] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.normalizer.my_normalizer.filter] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings","suppressed":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.normalizer.my_normalizer.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:253)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:231)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:205)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454)
```

I am using elasticsearch version 7.8. When i try to push the same setting via curl it works as expected. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `settings:{}` section:

```
String settings = "{\"analysis\":{\"normalizer\":{\"my_normalizer\":{\"type\":\"custom\",\"filter\":[\"lowercase\",\"asciifolding\"]}}}}";
```

Comment: i tried that option. In this case i see a different error. normalizer does not get recognized while i am trying to push the mapping. 
[type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=normalizer [lowercase_normalizer] not found for field [age]]

Comment: That's different, I don't see `lowercase_normalizer` in your settings string. Is there a field in the mapping that references it? maybe you need to add it to the settings or rename it to `my_normalizer`

Comment: yeah you were right. This was a silly mistake. And i have accepted the above solution as the answer. Thank you as always @Val